# SQLException error unhandled by user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So, I have a project that utilizes the Web Forms template in VS2013 and SQL Manager 2014. After much modifying, it seems to work up until the point one tries to change the details of any given user account.
Error given:

> An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in >EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed >while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This >could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to >respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this >server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=50001; handshake=0;

The line of code it occured on:

```
var hasLocalPassword = OpenAuth.HasLocalPassword(User.Identity.Name);
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: your DB server is not reachable ... that's why

Comment: How do I make it accessible? SQL Server is on and running so I really don't understand where the problem is.....

Comment: check  `connection timeout`  and set correctly and  **others** also you can check    don't use  **two**    `<add name="">`

Comment: Can you ping the SQL Server from the machine where you are running the code?

Comment: no. In fact, after removing time-out parameters, it fails on Open();